# Radio button Css Style

Tags: css, javafx-2

Below my radiobuttons I have something such as bottom padding, while I do not use any padding CSS statement

[image]

```
.radio-button {
-fx-font-family: "Arial";
-fx-font-size: 11;
/*    -fx-text-fill: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.4);*/
-fx-text-fill: lightgoldenrodyellow;
/*    -fx-effect: dropshadow(one-pass-box , rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 0, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );*/
-fx-border-width: 0px;
```

}

How to remove this? the radiobuttons seems not well centered.

**Edit:**

This is the hierarchy to show parents for radiobuttons

[image]

This is the visual appearance

[image]

And here the full CSS class

```
/* 
Created on : 20-gen-2014, 18.18.13
Author     : Alberto Pedroni <acepsut@gmail.com>
*/


.pane {
/*-fx-background-color: linear-gradient( #f0f8ff, #b0c4de);*/
//-fx-background-color: linear-gradient( cornsilk, tan);
/*-fx-background-radius: 5,4,3,5;
-fx-background-insets: 4,4,4,4;*/

}

.tab {

/*   -fx-background-color: red;  */
/*   -fx-border-color: gray;
-fx-border-radius: 4;
-fx-border-width: 1;*/

/*   -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(rgb(109,109,109), rgb(70,70,70));  */

/*   -fx-border-color: red;
-fx-border-radius: 4;
-fx-border-width: 1;*/

}

.tab-label {
-fx-font-size: 12px;
-fx-font-weight: bold;
-fx-text-fill: #333333;
-fx-effect: dropshadow( gaussian , rgba(255,255,255,0.5) , 0,0,0,1 );
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(aliceblue, lightslategray);
}

.label {

-fx-font-family: "Arial";
-fx-font-size: 11;
/*    -fx-text-fill: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.4);*/
-fx-text-fill: lightgoldenrodyellow;
/*    -fx-effect: dropshadow( one-pass-box , rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 0, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );*/

/*    -fx-text-fill: lightyellow;
-fx-font-size: 12px;
-fx-font-weight: bold;*/
/*    -fx-effect: innershadow( gaussian , rgba(255,255,255,0.5) , 0,0,0,1 );*/
}

.label > .tool-bar {

-fx-font-family: "Arial";
-fx-font-size: 11;
/*    -fx-text-fill: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.4);*/
-fx-text-fill: black;
/*    -fx-effect: dropshadow( one-pass-box , rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 0, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );*/

/*    -fx-text-fill: lightyellow;
-fx-font-size: 12px;
-fx-font-weight: bold;*/
/*    -fx-effect: innershadow( gaussian , rgba(255,255,255,0.5) , 0,0,0,1 );*/
}

.button .text {
-fx-effect: dropshadow(one-pass-box , rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), 0, 0.0 , 0 , -1 );
}

.button {
-fx-background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8),#090a0c,
    linear-gradient(#4a5661 0%, #1f2429 20%, #1f242a 100%), linear-gradient(#242a2e,    #23282e),
    radial-gradient(center 50% 0%, radius 100%, rgba(135,142,148,0.9), rgba(255,255,255,0));
-fx-background-radius: 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 5;
/*    -fx-background-insets: -3 -3 -4 -3, -3, 0, 1, 2, 0;*/
-fx-font-family: "Arial";
-fx-text-fill: white;
-fx-font-size: 12;
-fx-text-fill: linear-gradient(white, #d0d0d0);
/*    -fx-padding: 10 20 10 20;*/
}

.button-plot {
-fx-text-fill: red;
}

.button:focused, .button:hover {
-fx-background-color:
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08),
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8),
    #090a0c,
    linear-gradient(#4a5661 0%, #1f2429 20%, #1f242a 100%),
    linear-gradient(#3f4950, #23282e),
    radial-gradient(center 50% 0%, radius 100%, rgba(135,142,148,0.9),
    rgba(255,255,255,0));
}

.text-field, .text-area {
-fx-font-size: 12;
-fx-background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 50%), rgb(218, 226, 224);
-fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 0, 1.5;
-fx-background-radius: 6, 5, 4;
-fx-padding: 6 10 4 10;
-fx-effect: innershadow( gaussian, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), 5, 0, 0, 2 );
-fx-font-family: "Arial";
}

.text-area {
-fx-padding: 6 5 6 5;
}

.text-field:focused, .text-area:focused {
 -fx-background-color:
    rgb(235, 235, 235),
    rgb(0, 0, 0),
    rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.check-box {
-fx-font-family: "Arial";
-fx-font-size: 11;
/*    -fx-text-fill: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.4);*/
-fx-text-fill: lightgoldenrodyellow;
-fx-effect: dropshadow( one-pass-box , rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 0, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );
}

.combo-box, .choice-box {
-fx-font-size: 11;
-fx-background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 50%), rgb(218, 226, 224);
-fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 0, 1.5;
-fx-background-radius: 6, 5, 4;
/*    -fx-padding: 6 10 4 10;*/
-fx-effect: innershadow( gaussian, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), 5, 0, 0, 2 );
-fx-font-family: "Arial";
-fx-text-fill: black;
}

.radio-button {
-fx-font-family: "Arial";
-fx-font-size: 11;
/*    -fx-text-fill: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.4);*/
-fx-text-fill: lightgoldenrodyellow;
/*    -fx-effect: dropshadow(one-pass-box , rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 0, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );*/

}

.tool-bar{
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(aliceblue, lightslategray);
-fx-text-fill: black;
}

/*.titled-pane {

}*/

.titled-pane:focused {
-fx-text-fill: darkblue;
}

.titled-pane > .title {

-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(aliceblue, lightslategray);
-fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;
-fx-background-radius: 5 5 0 0, 4 4 0 0, 3 3 0 0;
-fx-padding: 0.166667em 0.833333em 0.25em 0.833333em; /* 2 10 3 10 */
}

/*.titled-pane:focused > .title 
{
-fx-color: -fx-focus-color;
}*/

/*.titled-pane > .title > .arrow-button 
{
-fx-background-color: null;
-fx-background-insets: 0;
-fx-background-radius: 0;
-fx-padding: 0.0em 0.25em 0.0em 0.0em;  0 3 0 0 
}*/

/*.titled-pane > .title > .arrow-button .arrow 
{
-fx-background-color: -fx-mark-highlight-color, -fx-mark-color;
-fx-background-insets: 1 0 -1 0, 0;
-fx-padding: 0.25em 0.3125em 0.25em 0.3125em;  3 3.75 3 3.75 
-fx-shape: "M 0 0 h 7 l -3.5 4 z";
}*/

/*.titled-pane:collapsed > .title > .arrow-button .arrow 
{
-fx-rotate: -90;
}*/

.titled-pane > *.content {
 /*    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(rgb(87, 87, 87), rgb(27, 27, 27));*/
/*    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(from 0% 0% to 0% 100%, rgb(102, 102, 102) 0%, rgb(0, 0, 0) 21%, rgb(102, 102, 102) 47%, rgb(0, 0, 0) 99%, rgb(0, 0, 0) 100%);*/
/*    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(rgb(70,78,95), rgb(40, 40, 40));*/
-fx-background-image:  url("file:///C:/Users/utente/Desktop/Java/NewProjectX/Backgrounds/CoarseGrid.png");
-fx-background-repeat: repeat;
-fx-background-color:
    linear-gradient(#38424b 0%, #1f2429 20%, #191d22 100%),
    linear-gradient(#20262b, #191d22),
    radial-gradient(center 50% 0%, radius 100%, rgba(114,131,148,0.9), rgba(255,255,255,0));

/*-fx-background-color:
-fx-box-border,
linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-color,-02%), derive(-fx-color,65%) 12%, derive(-fx-color,23%) 88%, derive(-fx-color,50%) 99%, -fx-box-border);
-fx-background-insets: 0, 0 1 1 1;
-fx-padding: 0.167em;*/
}

  .top-segment {
-fx-background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
-fx-border-color: 
    transparent transparent rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08) transparent,
    transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) transparent;
-fx-border-width: 1, 1.5;
-fx-border-insets: -1, 0; 
}

/*.titled-pane:focused > .title > .arrow-button .arrow 
{
-fx-background-color: white;
}*/

.split-pane:horizontal > * > .split-pane-divider {
/*   -fx-border-color: transparent; */
/*   -fx-box-border: transparent #BBBBBB;*/
/*   -fx-background-color: transparent, -fx-inner-border-horizontal;*/
/*    -fx-background-color: grey;*/
-fx-border-width: 0.1;
/*   -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 1 0 1;*/
}

.split-pane *.horizontal-grabber {
-fx-padding: 0;
-fx-background-color: transparent;
-fx-background-insets: 0;
-fx-shape: " ";
}
```

Comment: In the image it would appear you have duplicate radio buttons...can you include the HTML associated with this? Otherwise you can use the `vertical-align` property to adjust the position of the radio buttons.

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle where we can see your problem. And please add all the CSS related to the inputs.

Comment: Post how are you adding these radio buttons to scene. What is the parent of them?

Comment: Try by not adding any css file to the application. Is the problem solved? If yes, partially add css selectors to the css file and determine which css style resulting the problem.

Comment: ...@Uluk yes I found what css statement is liable for radiobuttons and checkboxes shadow, but I need this css for my GUI appearance

Answer (score 5):

```
.radio-button .radio {
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
}
```

This could help you.

Comment: That actually solves the problem @Rogutin. 
`.radio {
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
}` should suffise. 
You can't access the internal node except defining your own style in CSS. The `.radio` applies to the "button" itself. I had the same problem and ItachiUchiha helped me out there

Comment: edit to my previous comment: "You can't access the internal node through setStyle()"